# Unable to locate the jar in Maven Dependency Management

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency

I have 2 projects `testing.parent` and `testing.child`.
The project structure is as below:

[image]
Their individual poms are as below:

**testing.parent**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>testing.parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**testing.child**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing.child</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>testing.child</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>testing.group</groupId>
                <artifactId>testing.parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In order to test the `dependency management` I tried to `import` the `log4j` jar to `child` project but still the jar is not available in the child project. Is this the correct way to import the jars?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this link? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to import the jars?

*Yes*, include the log4j in the `dependency` section of the child `pom.xml`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version> <!-- version is optional when using dependency management -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

Also, make sure to refer the `parent` from the child as well, include the following in child `pom.xml` for that:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>testing.parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>testing.group</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

ensuring the similar reference in the parent `pom.xml` as

```
<modules>
    <module>testing.child</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: If I specifically need to include the log4j seperately in the dependency section then whats the use of having the dependency management section? I could have done the same thing without having all the additional sections of parent, dependency management etc and directly including the log4j.

Comment: *dependency management section* is mostly to control the version of the dependencies in a centralised way. you can read more about it in the docs https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: So just to conclude, in my case only importing the parent dependencies in dependency management wont make the log4j jar available in child. I have to additionally include it in the dependency section as well right?

Comment: @ghostrider Yes, unless it's anyway *available via some transitive dependencies*

Answer (score 0):

If you add below part to child pom.xml file, you don't need to import lof4j dependency separately though child pom.xml.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>testing.parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>testing.group</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I am aware of this. I wanted to check the benefits of dependency management. For dependency management its a 2 step process right?